# C# Windows Service - Multiple timers

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, timer

I'm developing a windows service that will need to do multiple tasks at different periods.

I currently have two timers, a full timer and a stock timer running at different intervals defined like below.

```
 fullTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
 fullTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
 fullTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(interval * 1000);
 fullTimer.AutoReset = true;
 fullTimer.Start(); // or fullTimer.Enabled = true;
 GC.KeepAlive(fullTimer);

   stockTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
   stockTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(StockOnElapsedTime);
   stockTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(stockInterval * 1000);
   stockTimer.AutoReset = true;
   stockTimer.Start();
   GC.KeepAlive(stockTimer);
```

Can anyone see why the timers wouldn't be firing. I'm getting really strange behaviour. If i fire the stock handler manually

```
StockOnElapsedTime(null,null);
```

The timer seems to continue to fire correctly.

Comment: If you want your posted code to look halfway decent, don't use `<code>` blocks. Just select it in the editor and press Control-K.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `Convert.ToDouble` calls.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs on [GC.KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx), I'd say that you might want to check that it's doing what you think it's doing.  The garbage collector will only guarantee to keep the objects alive between the start of the method to the point that KeepAlive is called.  Can you make these members of an object that'll stay around?

Answer (score 0):

You should store the `Timer` instances in fields.

Calling [`GC.KeepAlive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) will not keep an object alive indefinitely.

Comment: both the timers are declared as static

private static Timer stockTimer;

Comment: Does the service continue running? (Check its state in Services)

Answer (score 0):

As far as garbage collection goes, if the timer objects are both static class fields then the current instances of them will not be garbage collected unless you later set the fields to null or to a new object, so GC.KeepAlive is unnecessary (and it wouldn't have helped where it was being used anyway).  Where is this code being called, within OnStart?